# Difference in CSS3 :hover selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between these two

```
footer:hover a{}
```

and

```
footer a:hover{}.
```

This has been causing a bit of confusion in our CSS3 class and the research I have done into it hasn't shed much light on it.

Comment: Note that while your class calls it CSS3 presumably for the new technologies, the language itself is called "CSS", and `:hover` is not a new CSS3 feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
footer:hover a{}
```

Matches an `<a>` element which is a child of a `footer` element which is in `hover` state.

```
<footer>                                <---  hovered
    <a href="#">Some text</a><br/>      <--- both matched
    <a href="#">Some text 2</a>         <--- both matched
</footer>
<a href="#">Lost in dark</a>            <--- unmatched, as it's not a child of <footer>
```

---

```
footer a:hover{}
```

Matches an `<a>` which is being `:hover`ed on and is a child of a `<footer>` element.

```
<footer>
    <a href="#">Some text</a><br/>      <--- hovered, matched
    <a href="#">Some text 2</a>         <--- unmatched
</footer>
<a href="#">Lost in dark</a>            <--- hovered, but then also unmatched, as not a child of <footer>
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/RfC82/2/) to demonstrate difference.

Hope that makes it clear!

Answer (score 2):

`footer:hover a` is a pseudo selector. If you hover over any part of the footer, it will target the `<a>` element

For example

```
footer:hover a {
    background: red;
}
```

Hovering over any part of the footer will just give the link a background of red, and the footer css will not be changed.

---

`footer a:hover` selects any `a` elements that are child elements of footer. So if you hover over a link that is a child of a footer tag, it will do that css. This is different from the first example, in that you have to hover over the link to change the background of the link.. not just hover any part of the footer.

For example

```
footer a:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

---

Just trying things out yourself or seeing the code in an example can help a lot :
***[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/76K2m/)***

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pseudo selector". `footer:hover a` is very simply, a selector, of which one of the components, `:hover`, is a pseudo-class, which affects different elements depending on where you place it.

Answer (score 1):

`footer:hover a{}`

its define footer element inside a element to apply.

where as `footer a:hover{}`

its define footer element inside a element to apply hover effect.

### Check demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttfxc/)

#### HTML

```
<footer>
    <a href="#">Hello Stackoverflow</a>
</footer>
```

#### CSS

```
footer{
    width:300px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
footer:hover a{
    background-color: red;
}

footer a:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`footer:hover a{ color: red }` selects the anchor element and changes the color to red only when the footer is hovered.

`footer a:hover{ color: red}` changes the color of anchor element whenever it is inside footer and it is also hovered upon.

Take this example:

Assume the footer has other elements as well apart from anchor.

```
<footer>
  <div> I am div</div>
  <a> I am anchor </a>
</footer>
```

Now when you hover on div, in first case it will change the color of anchor to red. Because div is a part of footer and since the footer is also hovered, your selector applies and change its color.

Second example:

```
<a> Anchor 1: I am outside footer  </anchor>
<footer>
   <a> Anchor2: I am anchor </a>
</footer>
```

Now, in case 2, if you hover on anchor 1, it won't change the color to red because it is not inside footer while hovering on anchor 2 will change its color.